# How to show/hide Tab conditionally -React js

Tags: reactjs

I need a condition for the below code, when we go through the address id, it will show only the upgrade page tab and will go through bricks, it will show only the new purchase page tab only.
Now it is showing both tabs. I need one tab for conditonally. Please help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the selectActive tab to hide / display the tab of your choice like this:

```
<Row className="mt-3">
   <Col>
       <Tabs onSelect={selectTab} defaultActiveKey={selectActive()} id="uncontrolled-tab-example" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(237 245 240 / 38%)' }}>
       {selectActive() === "newPurchase" && (
        <Tab eventKey="newPurchase" title="New Webshop">
           <NewPurchase/>
       </Tab>
       )}
       {selectActive() === "upgrade" && (
       <Tab eventKey="upgrade" title="Existing Webshop">
            <Upgrade/>
       </Tab>
       )}
     </Tabs>
   </Col>
 </Row>
```

It will show / hide the tab depending upon the value returned from the function. By the way, your question needs more clarity

Comment: need help ondynamic tabs

Comment: you might wanna accept this answer first and ask a new question and then I can help.

Comment: The last time I accepted but I don't know why it is not showing green. Again accepted.

Comment: please help on how to write dynamic tabs. this is the sample  example  [{'name':'tab1','url':'/webshop/5654','component':NewPurchase
},{'name':'tab 2','url':'/webshop/upgrade/465765', 'component':Upgrade}]

Comment: Hi @venusri Can you please ask a new question with more details? I can not understand what you want just by the comment. You can post the link to. the comment here afterwards

Comment: Hi Saleem just posted this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282679/need-dynamic-tabs-for-the-below-code-react-js

Comment: please help with this