# Dynamic tabs for the below code - React js

Tags: reactjs

Hi how do create dynamic tabs? I wrote like this for 2 tabs. If it is more, it automatically adds those tabs. Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm little confused by what you want, but based on what I understand, you can try the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import HomenetPage from '../components/Page'
import { Row, Col, Tab, Tabs } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Upgrade from '../components/Upgrade'
import NewPurchase from '../components/NewPurchase'
import { useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Webshop = () => {
  const { addressid, brikksid } = useParams()
  const history = useHistory()

  const selectActive = () => {
    if (addressid) {
      return 'NewPurchase'
    }
    if (brikksid) {
      return 'Upgrade'
    }
  }

  const selectTab = (tab) => {

    selectedTab = tabsData.filter((data) => data.component === tab);
    history.push(selectedTab.url)
  }

  return (
        <HomenetPage>
          <Row className="mt-3">
        <Col>
            <Tabs onSelect={selectTab} defaultActiveKey={selectActive()} id="uncontrolled-tab-example" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(237 245 240 / 38%)' }}>
                {tabsData.map((key, index) => {
                    key.component === "NewPurchase" ? (
                        <Tab eventKey={key.component} onSelect={selectTab(key)} title={key.component} > <NewPurchase /></Tab>)
                    : key.component === "Upgrade" ? (
                        <Tab eventKey={key.component} onSelect={selectTab(key)} title={key.component} key={index}> < Upgrade /></Tab>)
                    : null
            })}
            </Tabs>
              </Col>
          </Row>
        </HomenetPage>
  )
}

export default Webshop
```

Comment: Ok I will check and let you know. thank u

Comment: through addressid it will go to upgrade page and brikkid it will got to purchase page.

Comment: how to set this part dynamically?                                                                                
    const selectActive = () => {
    if (addressid) {
      return 'newPurchase'
    }
    if (brikksid) {
      return 'upgrade'
    }
  }

Comment: I've updated the answer with complete code

Comment: Hi Saleem need help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452279/create-tablist-fo-the-below-in-react-js

Comment: please help with this